# Loop(array) on specific td created with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a cashier front that fetches the item ID in the database via PHP and returns its data such as price, unit and others on the screen and then I have the option to add this item to the list and/or finalize the sale.

The list is dynamically assembled into a table using innerHTML in the `<td>`.

My problem is in the following:

I have an item with 1 in stock, for example, and when I click to add it will check if it has 1 in stock and add it to the list, if I have already added the item and I don't have it in stock anymore, it returns an alert. I add the second item with different ID and same thing.

The validation I need is for it to run inside the `<td id="idProd">` and check if the product code exists, if it exists check if it still has stock and if so, add it, if it doesn't have stock it will return error. If it doesn't have the ID on the list, it checks the original stock and adds the product.

Below is the logic of this validation.

```js
var k = 0;

// Realiza o cálculo entre quantidade * valor retornando o campo Total
async function calcAddShop() {
  let forms = document.querySelector("#formsRegisterShop");
  var quantidadeItemShop = forms.elements.quantidadeItemShop.value;
  var valorItemShop = forms.elements.valorItemShop.value;

  calcAdd = quantidadeItemShop * valorItemShop;
  if (
    quantidadeItemShop == "" ||
    quantidadeItemShop == 0 ||
    valorItemShop == "" ||
    valorItemShop == 0
  ) {
    $("#totalItemShop").val("0");
  } else {
    $("#totalItemShop").val(calcAdd.toFixed(8));
  }
}

// Cria a lista de itens inseridos na tabela
async function addItemListShop() {
  let forms = document.querySelector("#formsRegisterShop");
  var codigoItemShop = forms.elements.codigoItemShop.value;
  var itemNameShop = forms.elements.itemNameShop.value;
  var estoqueItemShop = forms.elements.estoqueItemShop.value;
  var quantidadeItemShop = forms.elements.quantidadeItemShop.value;
  var valorItemShop = forms.elements.valorItemShop.value;
  var unidadeItemShop = forms.elements.unidadeItemShop.value;
  var totalItemShop = forms.elements.totalItemShop.value;

  // Cria linhas de itens comprados na tabela
  var item0 = '<tr class="trListProducts" id="listProducts' + k + '">';
  var item1 = '<td id="idProd">' + codigoItemShop + "</td>";
  var item2 = '<td id="nomeProd">' + itemNameShop + "</td>";
  var item3 =
    '<td id="quantProd" class="quantProd">' + quantidadeItemShop + "</td>";
  var item4 = '<td id="uniProd">' + unidadeItemShop + "</td>";
  var item5 = '<td id="valorProd">' + valorItemShop + "</td>";
  var item6 = '<td id="totalProd" class="totalProd">' + totalItemShop + "</td>";
  var item7 =
    '<td><a type="button" onclick="rmItemListShop(' +
    k +
    ')" class="btn btn-block btn-group-lg btn-danger form-control text-center" style="margin:0"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a></td>';
  var item8 = "</tr>";

  if (codigoItemShop) {
    if (estoqueItemShop == 0 || estoqueItemShop == "") {
      // Se estoque for igual a 0 ou vazio envia alerta
      alert("Produto sem estoque!");
    } else if (quantidadeItemShop > estoqueItemShop) {
      // Se quantidade comprada for maior que estoque disponível envia alerta
      alert("Quantidade inserida maior que a disponível em estoque!");
    } else {
      // Calcula a coluna QUANTIDADE e retorna a soma
      var sum_quantidade = 0;
      var sum_quantidade_format = 0;
      $('td[class*="quantProd"]').each(function() {
        sum_quantidade += Number($(this).text()) || 0;
        sum_quantidade_format = sum_quantidade.toFixed(8);
      });

      var tabela = document.querySelector("#tbodyListProducts");
      if (!$("#idProd").length) {
        console.log("Verificação 01");
        if (sum_quantidade_format > estoqueItemShop) {
          alert("Estoque insuficiente.");
        } else {
          if (quantidadeItemShop <= 0) {
            alert("Quantidade não pode ser menor que 1");
          } else {
            if (totalItemShop <= 0) {
              alert("Total não pode ser menor que 0.00000000");
            } else {
              tabela.innerHTML =
                tabela.innerHTML +
                item0 +
                item1 +
                item2 +
                item3 +
                item4 +
                item5 +
                item6 +
                item7 +
                item8;
              k++;
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Verificação 02");
        var idProduto = document.getElementById("idProd").innerText;
        var table = document.getElementById("tabelaProdutos");
        var tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
          var arrayTr = tr[i].innerText;
          var match = arrayTr.indexOf(codigoItemShop) > -1;
          console.log(match);
        }

        if (match) {
          console.log("Já possui o item na lista");
          if (sum_quantidade_format > estoqueItemShop) {
            alert("Estoque insuficiente.");
          } else {
            console.log("Possui estoque");
            tabela.innerHTML =
              tabela.innerHTML +
              item0 +
              item1 +
              item2 +
              item3 +
              item4 +
              item5 +
              item6 +
              item7 +
              item8;
            k++;
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Não possui o item na lista");
          tabela.innerHTML =
            tabela.innerHTML +
            item0 +
            item1 +
            item2 +
            item3 +
            item4 +
            item5 +
            item6 +
            item7 +
            item8;
          k++;
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    alert("Digite um código de produto!");
  }
  calcTotal();
}

async function calcTotal() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  var sum_format = 0.0;
  $('td[class*="totalProd"]').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).text()) || 0;
    sum_format = sum.toFixed(8);
  });

  if (sum == 0) {
    $("#totalCompra").text("0.00000000");
  } else {
    $("#totalCompra").text(sum_format);
  }
}

function rmItemListShop(id) {
  document
    .getElementById("tbodyListProducts")
    .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if ($("#idProd").length) {
        const node = document.getElementById("listProducts" + id) || {};
        if (node.parentNode != null) {
          node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
          calcTotal();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p class="card-text text-warning">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <b class="h1">FRENTE DE CAIXA</b>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <table class="table table-light table-striped table-shop">
        <thead>
          <tr class="header-pos-total">
            <th colspan="2">TOTAL</th>
            <th colspan="4" id="totalCompra">0.00000000</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <hr class="hr-forms-header">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <form method="POST" name="formsRegisterShop" id="formsRegisterShop" accept-charset="utf-8" class="text-white text-center form-shop">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="codigoItemShop" class="form-label text-warning">Código de Identificação</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="codigoItemShop" id="codigoItemShop" placeholder="" required autofocus>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="itemNameShop" class="form-label text-warning">Descrição</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="itemNameShop" id="itemNameShop" placeholder="" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="estoqueItemShop" class="form-label text-warning">Estoque</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="estoqueItemShop" id="estoqueItemShop" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="unidadeItemShop" class="form-label text-warning">Unidade</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="unidadeItemShop" id="unidadeItemShop" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="valorItemShop" class="form-label text-warning">Valor</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="valorItemShop" id="valorItemShop" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="quantidadeItemShop" class="form-label text-warning">Quantidade</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" class="form-control text-center" name="quantidadeItemShop" id="quantidadeItemShop" onchange="calcAddShop()" onkeyup="calcAddShop()" placeholder="" required autofocus>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="totalItemShop" class="form-label text-warning">Total</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="totalItemShop" id="totalItemShop" placeholder="" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning form-button form-control btn-shop" id="addItemShop" onclick="addItemListShop()">ADICIONAR ITEM</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success form-button form-control btn-shop" id="submitShop" onclick="submitShop()">FINALIZAR</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <form method="POST" name="formsAddOrderShop" id="formsAddOrderShop" accept-charset="utf-8" class="text-white text-center form-shop">
          <table class="table table-light table-striped table-shop" id="tabelaProdutos">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
                <th>Unidade</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Remover</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyListProducts">
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

An example of it working: https://codepen.io/spero_official/pen/GRymxJR

Comment: You can't use the same `id="idProd"` in every row. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: The code displayed in ```<td id="idProd">``` has a unique ID, registered in the database.
When you run the code, it will show you the true/false for when the ID is found in the column using the indexOf function.
For example, if I put item with id 1 in line 1 and try to add it again, indexOf returns true, indicating that the item is present in the column. When I add the item with id 2 in row 2, it allows the addition by returning false since 2 is not in the column. If I try to add 2 it will return true as it is now present on line 2.

Comment: Now comes the error: When I add the item with ID 1 in line 3, it does not recognize the true of line 1 and ignores it indicating false in indexOf.

Comment: Unrelated problem: You need to convert `estoqueItemShop` and `quantidadeItemShop` to integers before comparing them.

Comment: The problem is that you reassign `match` each time through the `for` loop. When you get to `if (match)`, it contains the value from the last item. You should break out of the loop when you find a match.

Comment: Why are you using `arrayTr.indexOf(codigoItemShop)`? If the user enters `1`, that will match an item with ID `10` or `21`. And why is the variable that holds the ID called `arrayTr`? It's a string, not an array.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you're getting the inner text of the entire row, not just the cell with the ID number. Why are you doing that? Use `var tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr td:first-child")` to get the cells with the ID number in each row.

Comment: The ```<td id="idProd">``` receives a barcode, so it answers it will have 13 unique digits, not being possible to be duplicated or get duplicates. The ```var match = arrayTr.indexOf(ItemShopcode) > -1;``` checks the complete line and returns true and false for each correct item in the console response, however the ```if(match)``` check that is not checking the array returned by indexOf. Test, for example, inserting data into the codepen of items with codes 7896089012460(item1) and 7896089012461(item2). First add item1, then item2 and finally item1 again, then check the output in the console.